# Disable Postback for Linkbutton

Tags: asp.net

Im using ASP.NET LinkButton.
I have a LinkButton which calls code behind from onclick:

on aspx:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkTest" runat="server" onclick="LinkTest_Click" OnClientClick="return false;"  >LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

on aspx.cs:

```
 protected void LinkTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code here
    }
```

As you can see I have set `OnClientClick="return false;"` so that it wont do a postback.
The postback does not happens. But the code behind is not fired.
I want the code behind to fire and I want no postback when the linkbutton is clicked.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide more details on the problem you are trying to solve outside of the LinkButton so I can provide an alternate solution. 

Since LinkButton is a Server Control, you cannot expect the server-side handler to be invoked if the client is setup to prevent the post back to the server (PostBack).  Based on your code, its doing what I expect it to do.

Comment: You are doing conflicting things, you are blocking postback but you want postback on click.

Comment: When the linkbutton is clicked I want the code behind to be executed but I do not want the refresh on the page. How can I do that?

Comment: Sounds like asynchronous post-back. Use an `UpdatePanel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `OnclientClick` attribute of the linkbutton. Try using an `UpdatePanel` like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkTest" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:label id="Label1" runat="server" Text="Initial Label" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Also, you will need to add a `ScriptManager` in your page.

Comment: Im trying it with the updatepanel. On the code behind method LinkTest_Click I have placed some text to a label: Label1.Text = "Test";. This code is executed, but on the page, the label text does not change at all.....How can I solve this?

Comment: Put the label mark-up inside the `ContentTemplate` portion (answer updated)

Answer (score 1):

Add the linkbutton inside updatepanel,
remove onclientclick attribute of the linkbutton:

Page:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Old Value"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtChange" runat="server" OnClick="lnkbtChange_Click">Change</asp:LinkButton>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void lnkbtChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblName.Text = "New value";
}
```

Comment: Im trying it with the updatepanel. On the code behind method LinkTest_Click I have placed some text to a label: Label1.Text = "Test";. This code is executed, but on the page, the label text does not change at all.....How can I solve this?

Comment: you should put the label too inside updatepanel, then it will work as expected